# I think mice have been eating my air plant. Can I save it?

Tags: houseplants, rodents

The past couple days, I've noticed the tips of my air plant have "come off" and I've also noticed mouse droppings in the bottom of the jar, so I"m assuming mice are eating it. Will it die simply from the tips being chewed off or can it be saved?

[image]

Comment: They will just "scar" but it shouldn't die.

Answer (score 1):

Tip damage of a larger succulent plant with multiple leaves will rarely kill an entire plant.  It may end up destroying some of the leaves, but they will just die back to the main stem and be replaced as the plant grows.

Comment: Giving it a dose of anti-fungal/anti-microbial might be a good preventative measure. I've had a number of cactus eaten by rodents, some quite severely. Most came through fine eventually.